# Guardar Dataset a table sql server en window form c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

buenas tardes estoy realizando que un datatable se guarde en una tabla de sql server pero me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo :

```
DataSet result;
   dataGridView1.DataSource = result.Tables[cboSheet.SelectedIndex];


            //string valor = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();



            foreach (DataRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
                con.Open();

    string sql = "INSERT INTO NumeroCredito (Numero1, Numero2) VALUES ('" + r["Columna3"] + "', '" + r["Columna5"] + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A", r["A"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@B", r["B"]);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día.

Prueba lo siguiente; en lugar del GridView.Rows usa el DataTable.Table.Rows; ya que de este último sabes cual Tables usar:

```
foreach (DataRow r in result.Tables[cboSheet.SelectedIndex].Rows)
{
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
   con.Open();

   string sql = "INSERT INTO NumeroCredito (Numero1, Numero2) VALUES ('" + r["Columna3"] + "', '" + r["Columna5"] + "')";
   SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = sql;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A", r["A"]);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@B", r["B"]);

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Leon Oramas excelente Maestro fue de gran ayuda.